# C# UWP Listview/GridView mark of selected item

Tags: c#, listview, uwp, marker

I am creating UWP app, and I maked external arrow "marker" of selected item in listview...

Like this:[image]

I have managed to achieve this with next code:

```
var current = lvMain.Items.FirstOrDefault(a => (a as MyModel).Selected) as MyModel;
ListViewItem selected = lvMain.ContainerFromItem(current) as ListViewItem;    
GeneralTransform generalTransform1 = gvEpg.TransformToVisual(selected);
Point currentPoint = generalTransform1.TransformPoint(new Point());
```

In Scroll change event I am calling this and set the arrow position by the Point of my item. And this is working.

But, I want to simplified this. Is there any kind of binding or something like that, that would make arrow always follow the item?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the sample.

XAML `MainPage`:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate">
        <Canvas Height="80" Width="200">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
        </Canvas>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>

<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <ListView x:Name="ListView" Width="400"
              SelectionChanged="ListView_OnSelectionChanged"
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DataTemplate}"/>

    <Canvas x:Name="ParentCanvas">
        <Image x:Name="Arrow" 
               Stretch="UniformToFill" Width="200" Height="80" 
               Source="Assets/Red_Left_Arrow.png"/>
    </Canvas>
</StackPanel>
```

Code behind:

```
    private readonly List<string> _names = new List<string>();
    private Visual _rectangleVisual;
    private Visual _parentVisual;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;
    }

    private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
        {
            _names.Add("item " + i);
        }

        ListView.ItemsSource = _names;

        _parentVisual = ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(ParentCanvas);
        _rectangleVisual = ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(Arrow);

        var border = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(ListView, 0) as Border;
        var scrollViewer = border.Child as ScrollViewer;

        var scrollerProperties = ElementCompositionPreview.GetScrollViewerManipulationPropertySet(scrollViewer);

        var offsetExpressionAnimation = _rectangleVisual.Compositor.CreateExpressionAnimation("Scroller.Translation.Y");
        offsetExpressionAnimation.SetReferenceParameter("Scroller", scrollerProperties);

        _rectangleVisual.StartAnimation("Offset.Y", offsetExpressionAnimation);
    }

    private void ListView_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var listViewItem = ListView.ContainerFromItem(ListView.SelectedItem) as ListViewItem;
        var listItemVisual = ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(listViewItem);

        _parentVisual.Offset = new Vector3(_parentVisual.Offset.X, listItemVisual.Offset.Y, 0);
    }
```

Looks like what you asked for:

[image]

Comment: Thanx, this is exactly what I was looking for. Just another thing, do you maybe know how to get notified when arrow goes out of view? So I can show some information if it's above or under the visible part of listview?

Comment: Sure, just add some `TextBlock` to XAML. Name it `x:name="TextBlock"` and add to the end of the `MainPage_Loaded` method: 

`var textExpression = _rectangleVisual.Compositor.CreateExpressionAnimation("-Arrow.Offset.Y - Parent.Offset.Y < 0 ? 1 : 0");
            textExpression.SetReferenceParameter("Parent", _parentVisual);
            textExpression.SetReferenceParameter("Arrow", _rectangleVisual);

            var textVisual = ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(TextBlock);
            textVisual.StartAnimation("Opacity", textExpression);`

Comment: This works if arrow goes above listview...what about if it goes under it?

Comment: omg... expand expression with one "if". I gave an example how to achieve it.